# Dual Boot Ubuntu 16.04.2-desktop on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Tags: dual-boot, mac

So I'm trying to do some bioinformatics work on my Mac to avoid having to move to another PC with Linux installed every time I want to analyze some data.

I have done my best to follow the instructions found on Ubuntu's website, but I still have not figured out how to get the dual boot to work on this Mac of mine.

Here are the specs of the Mac I'm working with: iMac, 32GB RAM, 1TB memory, OS X El Capitan v10.11.6. Here are the steps i've taken so far:

1. Partitioned HD to 600GB for Ubuntu & 400GB for OSX
2. Installed REFind
3. Downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso to desktop (also tried the amd64+mac version)
4. Downloaded unetbootin-mac-625 to desktop
5. Ran unetbootin to make flash drive bootable with Ubuntu 16.04.2 (**note: unetbootin said that ubuntu would not be bootable on a Mac)
6. When Mac is rebooted, REFind shows the Ubuntu OS as an option to boot from, selecting it gives a couple options of "try Ubuntu" or "install Ubuntu", etc. However, when any option is selected it just results in a black screen.
7. Then tried burning the .iso image onto a DVD, but then the Mac said that the DVD was "not readable by this computer".
8. Lastly, I tried the manual way of installing Ubuntu onto the flash drive (without unetbootin), and ended up with the same problem found in #6

Can anyone think of something I may have missed, or another way that I can run a Linuxx platform like Ubuntu on my Mac alongside OS X?

Answer (score 1):

I have a 27 inch, late 2009 iMac and have installed Ubuntu twice before to dual-boot. I believe it was Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04, my Mac OS was Snow Leopard back then. This black screen problem always happened.

What caused it was that Ubuntu thinks there's a 2nd screen output connected. I was able to solve it connecting my iMac to my TV using the miniDisplay adapter + HDMI cable. Then Ubuntu showed up on the TV screen and I could install it, reboot and then updated the graphics driver through Software Update, that fixed the problem.

If you have a TV or extra monitor, it's worth trying this. Even though your Mac and Ubuntu versions are newer, it may still be the same problem.

Also, there's another way around:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1578342&page=3&p=12255187#post12255187